# callback is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I am trying to pass a callback to a function, but keep getting the error,

**Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function.**

```
loadContacts: function () {

    var pageNumber = this.state.pageNumber,
        pageSize = this.state.pageSize;

    BasketService.getContacts(pageNumber, pageSize, function(contacts){
        contacts = this.convertPropertyNames(contacts);

        this.setState({
            contacts: contacts

        });
    }.bind(this));
},

// trying to pass function callback here
listenerForRemoveContact: function(data){
        BasketService.removePerson(data.id, this.loadContacts());

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    BasketService.removePerson(data.id, this.loadContacts);
```

^ you probably want to pass in the function object, not the result of calling the function

passing in

```
this.loadContacts()
```

will pass in the value which loadContacts returns (in this case it isn't returning anything)

Answer (score 1):

`this.loadContacts()` **calls** `loadContacts` and passes its *return value* to `removePerson`.

`loadContacts` doesn't have a `return` statement, so that value is `undefined`.

You are trying to use `undefined` as if it were a function.

If you want to pass `loadContacts` as the callback function, then *don't call it*: Remove the `()`.

Note that this will change the value of `this` inside the function, so you should also use `bind()` to maintain the context.

Answer (score 0):

Your code this.loadContacts() calls the function loadContacts and passes its return value to removePerson as argument.

loadContacts doesn't return anything, so the return value of that function is undefined.

If you want to pass loadContacts as the callback function, then don't invoke it just remove the invoking () from it.

Just pass like this 
removePerson(data.id, this.loadContacts);

That's it.